# How to prevent entry of a disabled date in bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

I am running uxsolutions / bootstrap-datepicker (https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker).

I have disabled dates in the popup calendar widget just fine (see code below). Yet in the date's textbox, I can enter a disabled date (screen shot below).

How can I get the date box to recognize disabled dates and prevent them from being able to be input?

```
  $('#eventDate-container .input-group.date').datepicker({
    weekStart: 1, // calendar starts on Monday
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    startDate: "4/10/2017", // disables all dates prior to this date
    datesDisabled: ['01/01/1970', '12/31/2099'] // placeholder sample for possible future use
  });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not the plugin you are using ([Bootstrap 3 Date/Time Picker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker)) but this might help...
I have been doing the same today, i started out with the exact plugin you are using, but then went to [Bootstrap 3 Date/Time Picker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker) because it has more options

[**Disable manual entry of date in , force selection via picker. #212**](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/212)

Comment: Cool, Thanks @McKabue. I'll look at that plugin later, but for the moment, I have uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker heavily, heavily used throughout my web app so switching at the moment would be monumental I just need to solve my immediate problem.

Comment: You can try forcing the user to use the picker directly and disable the input

Comment: Ok, thanks @McKabue, not a great nor desirable option...but you are correct, it is an option, nonetheless.

Comment: +try adding readonly="readonly" to the input or disabled="disabled" [might result to some side effects]

Comment: No (sorry) @McKabue but you are circumventing the issue and bypassing OQ. (1) I need to allow the user to enter a date in the textbox. (2) I need that textbox to follow the date disabled rules in bootstrap-datepicker. (3) I need to continue to use uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker plugin. So can this be achieved or is this plugin too weak and incapable of providing?

Answer (score 0):

I patched the code:

```
keydown: function(e){
    case 13: // enter
        if (!this.o.forceParse)
            break;
        **if (this.picker.find('td.focused.day').hasClass('disabled'))
            break;**
        focusDate = this.focusDate || this.dates.get(-1) || this.viewDate;
        if (this.o.keyboardNavigation) {
            this._toggle_multidate(focusDate);
            dateChanged = true;
        }
```